# maven-compiler files exclusion and Netbeans 7.1

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

In my POM, I've configured the maven-compiler-plugin to exclude a test file (using  element) and Eclipse automatically detects this in the POM and configure the .classpath file.

But it seems it's not the same with Netbeans. Any idea?

Assuming Netbeans doesn't support this feature, I don't see where I can configure Netbeans to exclude some files from compilation.

Thanks

Comment: I've found that a bug is opened concerning Maven compiler exclusion for who is interested: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that a bug is opened concerning Maven compiler exclusion for who is interested: [netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99588](http://www.netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99588)