# Eclipse/Netbeans IDE choice in a Maven-using Java EE development team

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

If I'm using Maven to manage my Java EE web services projects, are there any reasons to standardize on Eclipse or NetBeans vs allowing developers on the team to use whatever IDE they're most comfortable working with?  I've tested this by creating a couple of trivial test projects and making sure I can load, build, and run unit tests - a simple console app that reads off of ActiveMQ, and a basic servlet app.

My assessment heretofore is that there aren't any compelling technical reasons not to let people simply use whatever they want.

Am I correct, or are there any "gotchas" here I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just finished testing Netbeans 7.1, Eclipse 3.7 (with m2e-wtp installed) and IntelliJ 11 Ultimate.

All three work very well with Maven projects and I have found no reason not to use the best IDE for a given job.

Comment: Note:  You still need a build engine for running the tests after each checkin to verify that the underlying projects are still ok.  Also, file encoding should be dealt with explicitly in the project if you develop on multiple platforms/locales.

Comment: Hi, I've just seen your answer, maybe you can help me to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877263/maven-compiler-files-exclusion-and-netbeans-7-1  ?? :) Thanks

Comment: We do not exclude files from compilation.  I do not know.  If command line maven does work correctly it is a bug in Netbeans, and you should report it to Oracle.

Comment: Note:  We found that source reformatting is very hard to get identical on all platforms potentially polluting the version control commits.  In a mixed environment you need to find a policy that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should let people use whatever IDE they want, no matter how well it integrates with Maven.

Let them use Emacs or Vim if they want. Let them use Notepad++ and the command line.

That said, I've been consistently unhappy with Eclipse's Maven plugins. I'm not familiar enough with modern NetBeans to have an opinion. Intellij is usually great except for an issue with version ranges.

Comment: Haha Vim and Emacs. +1 for that. For the record, I agree with everyone else that said that IDE pretty much doesn't matter anymore. Use whatever you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

It honestly should not matter, it is about the expertise of your development team.  If you have developers who are most productive with Eclipse, let them use eclipse, if they like IntelliJ use it.  I have used all three (NetBeans, Eclipse, and IntelliJ) they all pretty much do the same types of things.  After you learn the basics, it becomes about how well you know the tips and tricks type stuff (e.g. how to do code completion, class/code searches, etc. with key commands) that separates one IDE from the next.  As long as your team has solid deploy procedures, then they should be fine.  That may actually work better because when you do bring someone new aboard you've got a bunch of IDE expertise across the IDE landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I am working for a big northern bank and here we take whatever we are comfortable with. Together with Maven we didn't experience anything what should be stopping us from that.

[sven.malvik.de](http://sven.malvik.de)

Answer (score 0):

There are unfortunately also reasons to prescribe some IDE. If there are unskilled programmers, there is peer programming where two work together at one keyboard.